# cassandra: ~.cqlshrc does not work for float_precision

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I created file in `.cassandra` directory and changed the `cqlshrc` file.

```
[ui] float_precision = 10
```

But that did not work. I am using `ccm` with Cassandra in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `cqlshrc` file, you need to designate your `[ui]` section and define your `float_precision` on separate lines.  In your example, it shows that you are defining them on the *same* line.

Here you can see that I have my `cqlshrc` file defined as you do.  When querying a float in cqlsh, it defaults to a precision of 5.

```
aploetz@dockingBay94:~$ cat .cassandra/cqlshrc
[ui] float_precision = 10

aploetz@dockingBay94:~$ cqlsh -u aploetz -p aploetz
Connected to VaporTrails at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.1 | CQL spec 3.3.1 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
aploetz@cqlsh> use stackoverflow ;
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROm floattest;

 id                                   | value
--------------------------------------+---------
 d79fee54-e67b-4178-bfc9-155ffe6a9372 | 5.82375

(1 rows)
```

But when I put them on separate lines, it properly enforces my desired float precision:

```
aploetz@dockingBay94:~$ cat .cassandra/cqlshrc
[ui]
float_precision = 10

aploetz@dockingBay94:~$ cqlsh -u aploetz -p aploetz
Connected to VaporTrails at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.1 | CQL spec 3.3.1 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
aploetz@cqlsh> use stackoverflow ;
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROm floattest;

 id                                   | value
--------------------------------------+--------------
 d79fee54-e67b-4178-bfc9-155ffe6a9372 | 5.8237495422

(1 rows)
```