# How to change the float precision in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, precision

We tried to change the float_precision by changing in cqlshrc but it didn't work . is there any method to using cqlshrc ?

Comment: How did you change float_precision in cqlshrc? Did you create ~/.cqlshrc file for this?

Comment: I answered a similar question here, that was ironically asked on the same day: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34370958/cassandra-cqlshrc-does-not-work-for-float-precision